# Is it possible to create an element with DomDocument where the opening and closing tags are different?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I know this sounds odd but I have a special situation where I need to create an xml (actually this won't be an xml document anymore because of the different closing tag) where the root opening tag is different from the root closing tag. Like:

```
<OPENING_TAG>
   <ONE></ONE>
   <TWO></TWO>
   <THREE></THREE>
</CLOSING_TAG>
```

Again I know this is not right but as I have mentioned this is a special case where the opening and closing tags have to be different. How can I accomplish that with DomDocument?

Comment: Just to ask - why do you need this, would it be better to change whatever is consuming the result to handle properly formed XML.

Comment: @NigelRen Of course it would be (more than) better to fix the consuming part but it is not up to me. It is an old desktop software I have to use.

Comment: OK - sometimes I've worked with third parties who ask for odd things and it can be difficult to persuade them to change their software.  But it's sometimes a case of pointing out to them that there system is wrong for them to do something.  But if it's not an option then shame.

Comment: @NigelRen I have asked many times for this. I told them that there is no way for an xml with extinct tags. But they could not change it. Actually it is a huge shame. A shame at the first place where they started to code it like that.

Comment: A DOM document is a tree of nodes, in which each element node has a name. There's no place in a DOM node to hold two separate names. What you're describing isn't XML, so if you want to do it, you will have to use non-XML tools.

Comment: Let's be clear, there is nothing wrong with this. If you want to devise a new data format that's quite different from XML, you're perfectly free to do so. But you'll have to build all the tooling from the ground up, so it will be expensive. Don't expect any help from XML tools or XML people, and don't tag your questions "XML". There's a good reason for sticking to standards: it reduces everyone's costs. But if you want to pay the costs of being different, that's your call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you seem to want to do is create an invalid XML document.  DOMDocument won't allow you to do that - it makes no sense.  SO the answer is No you can't.

If you want to create the document your after, create it as text directly.

Comment: I'd add, it's even beyond 'invalid", the document needs to be considered as well formed (see https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-wellformed). Having closing tags matching the opening tags is a requirement

Comment: I know that it will be invalid. Yep editing it after it was created (as a string) is the way I am using currently.

Comment: You are right @krampstudio. I know that and I told that it is odd. And actually it is not an xml anymore.

Comment: Yes, but it's the reason why DomDocument will fail loading your string. You may have a chance trying to load it using `loadHtml` but it will probably ignore the closing tag

Comment: @krampstudio yep you that is right this is exactly the reason for the fail. that could be another solution. But there is only one tag that has to change. So I think the shortest way is to go with the str_replace() after the string is created.

Answer (score 0):

No, DOM doesn't allow invalid XML document. If it is necessary to create opening and closing tags, you can write xml like below (if it suits your requirement):

```
<MAIN_TAG>
   <OPENING_TAG></OPENING_TAG>
   <ONE></ONE>
   <TWO></TWO>
   <THREE></THREE>
   <CLOSING_TAG></CLOSING_TAG>
<MAIN_TAG>
```

Or you can create it as a simple string (text).